# how to synchronize three dependent threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, multiprocessing, multitasking

If I have

```
1. mainThread: write data A, 
2. Thread_1: read A and write it to into a Buffer;
3. Thread_2: read from the Buffer.
```

how to synchronize these three threads safely, with not much performance loss? Is there any existing solution to use? I use C/C++ on linux.

IMPORTANT: the goal is to know the synchronization mechanism or algorithms for this particular case, not how mutex or semaphore works.

Comment: I use C/C++, if the language matters

Comment: Of course it matters, high level languages (java, C# etc) have simplified the whole process with native constructs. I'd suggest re-tagging your question to include a C++ tag.

Comment: What platform? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Pipeline threading model looks best for this. If you need more info on that download the sorces in the book "Programming with Posix threads". Sorry, dont have the link with me now

Comment: Read/write to/from what?  Disk file?  Surely there is something else going on else the data could be just written to the buffer in main, the buffer written to disk in 1 and then just passed to thread 2.

Comment: You are right Martin, there is something else going on to process the data. But the main question is how to better synchronize three dependent threads.

Comment: It's difficult without knowing more details.  Looking at what I see, I would make A and Buffer the same buffer object class instance.  When one is 'full', queue it off on a producer-consumer queue to Thread_1, write it, (to something), then queue it off to Thread_2.  The main thread would just create another A/buffer instance after queueing the first one off.  No locking except that breifly required to shove an instance onto a queue and any A/Buffer instance is only ever operated on by one thread.  I don't know if that would work for your app 'cos insufficient detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd consider the possibility of building this as three separate processes, using pipes to connect them. A pipe is (in essence) a small buffer with locking handled automatically by the kernel. If you do end up using threads for this, most of your time/effort will be spent on creating nearly an exact duplicate of the pipes that are already built into the kernel.

Second, if you decide to build this all on your own anyway, I'd give serious consideration to following a similar model anyway. You don't need to be slavish about it, but I'd still think primarily in terms of a data structure to which one thread writes data, and from which another reads the data. By strong preference, all the necessary thread locking necessary would be built into that data structure, so most of the code in the thread is quite simple, reading, processing, and writing data. The main difference from using normal Unix pipes would be that in this case you can maintain the data in a more convenient format, instead of all the reading and writing being in text.

As such, what I think you're looking for is basically a thread-safe queue. With that, nearly everything else involved becomes borders on trivial (at least the threading part of it does -- the processing involved may not be, but at least building it with multiple threads isn't adding much to the complexity).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say how much experience with C/C++ threads you have. I hate to just point to a link but have you read up on `pthreads`?

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

And for a shorter example with code and simple mutex'es (lock object you need to sync data):

http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs460ta/cs460/labs/pthreads.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread.html) for this purpose. This is quite good framework with mutexes and semaphores, *and* it is multiplatform. [Here](http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html) you can find very good tutorial about this.

How *exactly* synchronize these threads is another problem and needs more information about your problem.

---

**Edit** The simplest solution would be to put two mutexes -- one on `A` and second on `Buffer`. You don't have to worry about deadlocks in this particular case. Just:

1. Enter `mutex_A` from `MainThread`; `Thread1` waits for mutex to be released.
2. Leave mutex from `MainThread`; `Thread1` enters `mutex_A` and `mutex_Buffer`, starts reading from `A` and writes it to `Buffer`.
3. `Thread1` releases both mutexes. `ThreadMain` can enter `mutex_A` and write data, and `Thread2` can enter `mutex_Buffer` safely read data from `Buffer`.

This is obviously the simplest solution, and probably can be improved, but without more knowledge about the problem, this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: I dont think it answers the question. for OP "synchronize these threads is another problem" is not another problem but THE problem.